# Is there a way to pass an Apollo query selection through react props?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

The way that react Apollo calls to populate the data prop

```
   graphql(withQLTag)(ReactComponent)
```

exists outside the component class.

But what if I want to control which data I use via the react prop by predefined queries so that I can reuse a list for multiple data models?(I know the list view would have to pull from properties that exist in all data returned)

```
   render() {
       return(
          <ReactComponent qlTag="Model1">
       )...
```

Is there a way to pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make as many wrapped components as you like:

```
import MyListComponent from './somewhere';

const ProductListComponent = graphql(ProductListQuery)(MyListComponent) 
const EventListComponent = graphql(EventListQuery)(MyListComponent) 
const SomethingElseListComponent = graphql(SomethingElseListQuery)(MyListComponent)
```

Think of the `graphql` wrapper as just creating a component that passes in some props.